# How to encrypt using credentials of the current Windows user in powershell for KeePass?

Tags: .net, powershell, encryption, keepass

I need to write a script that encrypts a string the same way that the [`{PASSWORD_ENC}`placeholder](https://keepass.info/help/base/placeholders.html#passwordenc) is encrypted in KeePass:

> {PASSWORD_ENC} – Encrypting Passwords:
>
> The {PASSWORD_ENC} placeholder
>   is replaced by the password of the current entry in encrypted form.
>   **The password is encrypted using credentials of the current Windows
>   user.** The encrypted password should not be stored and only works for
>   the current user.

(emphasis mine)

How can I encrypt a string programmatically to get the same encrypted password as the one I would get in KeePass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the KeePass source code (`\KeePassLib\Utility\StrUtil.cs`)

```
private static readonly byte[] m_pbOptEnt = { 0xA5, 0x74, 0x2E, 0xEC };

public static string EncryptString(string strPlainText)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPlainText)) return string.Empty;

    try
    {
        byte[] pbPlain = StrUtil.Utf8.GetBytes(strPlainText);
        byte[] pbEnc = ProtectedData.Protect(pbPlain, m_pbOptEnt,
            DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

#if (!KeePassLibSD && !KeePassRT)
        return Convert.ToBase64String(pbEnc, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
#else
        return Convert.ToBase64String(pbEnc);
#endif
    }
    catch(Exception) { Debug.Assert(false); }

    return strPlainText;
}
```

Fortunately, we can use .NET members in PowerShell and do the same thing:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Security') | Out-Null;
[byte[]] $m_pbOptEnt = @(0xA5,0x74,0x2E,0xEC);
$plainBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes( "my super strong password is 123456" );
$cipherBytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($plainBytes, $m_pbOptEnt, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser);
$cipherPw = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cipherBytes);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong as I am not a cryptography expert but this sounds like how PowerShell `SecureString`s already work. It is only good for the user and machine that generated it. Making on is a matter of just doing something like `$Credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString` where `$credential` is a `[PSCredential]` object.

Comment: @Matt Yes, when you use ConvertTo-SecureString and ConvertFrom-SecureString without a Key or SecureKey, Powershell will use Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) to encrypt/decrypt your strings. This will use the same functions as the ones I used in my answer but not with the same parameters as what is needed to be decrypted by KeePass (e.g the entropy).